# Websocket suspension in 2-websocket mode

Tags: javascript, gwt, websocket

We have GWT application with 2 websocket which are working simultaneously. The 1st is for ping-pong with server and the 2nd is for all other commands. While i'm receiving big (~2MB) answer from the 2nd connection and render a table by this answer's data, I've noticed 1st connection is suspended and I can't send pings and receive pongs?
What the problem? And is there ways to resolve it?
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that JavaScript is single threaded. So while your big data is being rendered everything else is waiting for it to be finished. To solve your problem you should send your data back in small blocks and process these blocks such that in between the blocks the browser will give processing to the 1st websocket.